# Values not clearing in JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I am finding it hard to clear the value of `JFormattedTextField`s. How to do it?

I tried

```
txtJFormattedTextField.setText("");
```

But when focus is lost again the value that I cleared away will appear. I read the API regarding this issue.

My factory for creating JTFormattedTextFields for Date fields is below -

```
public static JFormattedTextField createDateField() {
        MaskFormatter maskFormatter = null;
        try {
            maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(
                maskFormatter);
        SwingHelper.installDateValidation((AbstractDocument) formattedTextField
                .getDocument());
        formattedTextField.setColumns(10);
        return formattedTextField;
    }
```

Tried the

```
try {
    ((JFormattedTextField) txtSigninDate).commitEdit();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result was an exception - below is the exception trace.

```
java.text.ParseException: stringToValue passed invalid value
    at javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter.stringToValue(MaskFormatter.java:456)
    at javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter.stringToValue(MaskFormatter.java:371)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.commitEdit(JFormattedTextField.java:530)
    at app.view.action.Authentication_Action.clearSigninFields(Authentication_Action.java:207)
    at app.view.action.authentication.AuthenticationCommand.decorateSignout(AuthenticationCommand.java:285)
    at app.view.action.authentication.AuthenticationCommand.executeSignin(AuthenticationCommand.java:122)
    at app.view.action.Authentication_Action$2.actionPerformed(Authentication_Action.java:292)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.depends of used `Formatter`

```
JFormattedTextField.setValue(0.00);
```

2.or `MaskFormatter`

```
JFormattedTextField.setValue(null);
```

3.is possible to set `null` value for `JFormattedTextField` with `Formatter`, but I'd suggest to use proper value for concrete `Formatter`, e.g. for `NumberFormatter` to set `setValue(0.00)`

4.for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html), otherwise your question probably isn't answerable,

Comment: I posted the Factory. Sorry for not adding a SSCCE. But I found that the `JFormattedTextField.setValue(null);` does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behavior you are seeing is that a `JFormattedTextField` reverts to the last valid value on `focusLost` and on `commit`. Typically your code should interact with such a field using the getter and setter for the `value`, and not for `text` as with a regular `JTextComponent`.

So the solution is setting a value which is formatted by the formatter by an empty String.

Consult the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the JFormattedTextField will return the old value put in when using a formatter factory is it verifies the input or lack thereof when the focus is lost from the field.

The answer to this is simple found it on the java docs website 
In your case this is how it works

```
txtJFormattedTextField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
```

add this line after the creation of your textfield and when the focus is lost it will not attempt to verify the input any longer in other words keeping the current value of the field even if it is "invalid"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you add a link to the java docs you mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
formattedTextField.commitEdit();
```

after setting text;

Comment: The poster ir referring to the focus behavior, not setting values programmatically.